# public static list individual items

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

How to get the individual value of a public static list

```
//get value error
Console.WriteLine(lbl_test.module_a.moduleoutput[0]);


public static List<string> moduleoutput()
{
    List<string> output = new List<string>();
    output.Add("test 1");
    output.Add("test 2");
    output.Add("test 3");
    return output;
}
```

Error:
**Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'**

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Comment: What is `lbl_test.module_a`? Is it the namespace and class? Second of all, `moduleoutput` in your first line of code is some variable and not the function call to your static function `moduleoutput()`.

Comment: @Styxxy. yes the list is located in class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the list first before you can access it by the indexer. So the method call is missing(the parentheses). `moduleoutput` is a method not a variable.

```
Console.WriteLine(lbl_test.module_a.moduleoutput()[0]);
```

Search for *Method Access* here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx

> Calling a method on an object is like accessing a field. After the
>   object name, add a period, the name of the method, and parentheses.
>   Arguments are listed within the **parentheses**, and are separated by
>   commas.

Answer (score 2):

That's a method, not a property. You have to call the method.

You probably want it to be a property:

```
public static List<string> moduleoutput 
{
    get 
        { 
            List<string> output = new List<string>();
            output.Add("test 1");
            output.Add("test 2");
            output.Add("test 3");
            return output;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are calling it wrong. You are calling `moduleoutput` as a variable rather than a method. You forgot the brackets:

```
Console.WriteLine(lbl_test.module_a.moduleoutput()[0]);
```

Example code below works perfectly:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Moduleoutput()[0]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static List<string> Moduleoutput()
    {
        List<string> output = new List<string>();
        output.Add("test 1");
        output.Add("test 2");
        output.Add("test 3");
        return output;
    }
}
```